# Import module from another directory for Unit Tests

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have the following directory structure:

```
Master
-------Tests
|-----------test_extract.py
-------Scripts
|-----------extract.py
```

This I'm trying to do a unit test file for extract.py. However, I'm receiving the following error:

> "not {}".format(type(path)))
>
> RuntimeError: 'path' must be None or a list, not  >'_frozen_importlib_external._NamespacePath'>

This is how I'm trying to import the extract module:

```
import unittest
import sys
print (sys.path[0])
sys.path.insert(0, sys.path[0]+'\\Scripts')
from Scripts import extract
```

I'm using Python 3.5. Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you do it `sys.path.insert(0, sys.path[0]+'\\Scripts')`? Did you try just import packege to test module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
import sys, os
myPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, myPath + '/../')

from Scripts import extract
```